# what could this error mean (I am using Unity)?

Tags: unity-game-engine, cinemachine

I tried to download Cinemachine and got the error below so I removed it and then this error popped up again. Help :(

Assets\Samples\Cinemachine\2.8.9\Cinemachine Example Scenes\Shared\Scripts\InvokeEventFromInspector.cs(6,19): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Editor' does not exist in the namespace 'Cinemachine' (are you missing an assembly reference?)

Comment: you need to remove the folder specified in the path

Answer (score 0):

Without having checked, but you can try removing the sample scene folder and see whether that solves it